# Register file type as a script

Tags: windows, windows-10

File types like `.bat`, `.exe`, and `.vbs` allow you to drag and drop files on top of them and then those files automatically get passed as parameters to that file type. Is there a way to set this to work for custom file types?

I.e., I have a filetype `.dan` that runs with `Dans.exe` in the format `Dans testFile.dan arg1 arg2 argn`. Can I register `.dan` to have file paths passed to it they are dropped on it?

Comment: Look at HKCR\.bat  HKCR\batfile (batch files are a little special.. but only a little).  Look at HKCR\.js, HKCR\JSFile.  Look at the environment variable PATHEXT.  For JScript, you will note that the Shell->Open->Command is `C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*`  the %1 and %* are what pass params to it.  The PATHEXT allows you to run your .dan file as a program even though it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to configure the registry. Fortunately you can do it without administrator privileges.

The four things you need are:

- An extension key that contains the default prog ID to launch the file with
- A prog ID that contains

  - the command for opening the file
  - the file drop handler - this is what enables drag and drop
- The hash of the prog ID set in the user choice for the file extension

This looks a little like

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dotnetScriptFile\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Dan\\Dans.exe\" \"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\dotnetScriptFile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{60254CA5-953B-11CF-8C96-00AA00B8708C}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.csx\OpenWithProgids]
"dansFile"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.csx\OpenWithList]
"a"="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\\OpenWith.exe"
"MRUList"="ba"
"b"="dans.exe"
```

To actually generate this information, I used a modified version of [PS-SFTA](https://github.com/DanysysTeam/PS-SFTA) which can be found [here](https://github.com/DanJBower/PS-SFTA). Using the PowerShell scripts from the repo, you can run the following commands in a command prompt that will add the keys to your registry.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "& { . .\SFTA.ps1; Register-FTA-Command '"""%USERPROFILE%\Dans.exe""" """%%1""" %%*' '.dan' 'danFile' -Verbose }"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "& { . .\RegisterDropHandler.ps1; RegisterDropHandle 'danFile' -Verbose }"
```

Some things to be aware of:

- The has for `a` in the `OpenWithList` is pretty complex to generate so can't be copy and pasted. Unfortunately this is why the PowerShell scripts are required.